# Problems in installation of XC 9.2

Tags: sitecore-commerce, installation

I tried `Sitecore XC 9.2 installation` and found the following issues on my machine:

1. During the installation, Visual Studio Just-In-Time Debugger window got popped up several times, every time I just selected the "`No, cancel debugging`" option to continue.

[image]

2. During `Bootstrap`, `RunMinion`, and `Generate Catalog Templates installation` steps I found below the Application startup exception in the commerce engine service

```
00001 23:16:24 INFO Application startup exception
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression.IResponseCompressionProvider' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression.ResponseCompressionMiddleware'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0(RequestDelegate next)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Internal.ApplicationBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
```

To resolve the issue, I disabled the compression setting in all commerce engine configuration files at the below locations:

- CommerceAuthoring\wwwroot\config.json
- CommerceMinions\wwwroot\config.json
- CommerceOps\wwwroot\config.json
- CommerceShops\wwwroot\config.json

Restarted IIS AppPool and then continued with installation.

I want to know what should be done to avoid the above issues during installation.

Answer (score 1):

Were the `w3wp` crashes during the installation of Sitecore modules?

They look very similar to this xConnect crash KB: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/494291

If you are on a Windows 10 build older than 1809, could you try installing the "`.NET Framework November 2018 Security and Quality Rollup`" as mentioned in the KB solution?

If you are on `Windows 10 1809 or newer`, could you try the binding redirect workaround in your Sitecore instance?

Before:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

After:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: Yes i can see w3wp crash entries in windows event viewer. My windows version is 1803 so i will try installing ".NET Framework November 2018 Security and Quality Rollup". Will this also resolve the "Application Startup" issue in commerce engine service that i mentioned above?

Comment: I doubt it will help for the Commerce Engine issue. I have no clue for this one.

Comment: Sitecore just updated the KB article to cover more than xConnect: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/494291

Comment: I upgraded to windows version 1903 and the first problem is not coming now, thanks. But second issue is still there.